# How to create a NuGet package for two different OS

Tags: .net-core, nuget

My project is compiled with different symbolic directives #define for different OS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-define

I want to create a NuGet package that will install the required library for the corresponding system. 
How can i do this?

Comment: Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397501/nuget-references-to-assemblies-in-runtimes-folder-not-added/52526376?noredirect=1#comment91995624_52526376